# Calculated date measure to show default min and max is not working in Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am very new to power bi DAX and I don't figure out why my measure is not working properly. So I have created one measure to for date and applied that to visual level filter to default data to always show the last x months or all data where applicable. So far it is giving me the date range between min and max but visuals are not updating according to default date range. When I change date range then my visuals are get updated. I want my visual with latest default date and data. Please let me know how can I
accomplish this.
**Note: I applied this measure on slicer which showing date range.**

Here is the measure that I have applied:

```
Min_Max_ad_srch = VAR LatestDate = CALCULATE(MAX(ADS[DATE]), ALL(ADS)) RETURN IF(MIN(ADS[DATE]) = LatestDate, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display a fixed set of data in a visual, and to have it not change when other selections are made.

You would best accomplish this not through filtering the visual but by applying the filtering condition to the measure that the visual is displaying.

So, you would use something like:

```
My Measure (for Latest Date) = 
VAR LatestDate = CALCULATE(MAX(ADS[DATE]), ALL(ADS)) RETURN
CALCULATE([a Measure], ALL(ADS[DATE]), ADS[Date] = LastestDate)
```

using `ALL(ADS[DATE])` effectively ignores any selection made in ADS[DATE], and subsequently saying `ADS[DATE] = LatestDate` applies the date filter you're asking for.

With this formula in your visual, you will always show data for the latest date, regardless what other date selections are made.

Comment: I am quite not sure what is CALCULATE([a Measure]) ? What I need to provide there? Also, how can I use this measure because previously I applied this measure on visual level and filter it to "is 1". Also, I want my Data to be change according to my date visual. So suppose I applied my above measure "Min_Max_ad_srch " then it showing me date "3/31/2021 - 3/31/2021" but visuals/data are as it is. I want my visual/data to be show latest "3/31/2021 - 3/31/2021" date data as soon as I apply my measure but that's not happening unless I manually filter on date.

Comment: The 'CALCULATE' function basically says: "evaluate this formula, or measure as if this filter were applied', so my little pseudocode up there just means that you would put the name of the measure you're trying to calculate in that space. 
That said, it looks like I misunderstood your question, and I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish based on your description.

Comment: I got your point. Could please suggest me if is there any way to set the default  min-max date range to be show last month of data only instead of earlier min and latest max?

Comment: so basically what I want is ,so suppose today's date is 4/5/2021 then I want my date slicer to show the date range between 4/3/2021 to 4/5/2021 by default and my widgets should reflect the latest data according to date. Also, I don't have any 'Date' or 'Calender' table and even I don't know how to create/use them. I am using date column which is associated with my original table. " Note: we are using 'Direct Query' to database." Please let me know how can I accomplish this. I have tried different measures of power BI community but none of them worked.

Comment: Got it. Now I understand. The short answer is, you can't do this in Power BI. There are a variety of workaround strategies, but not directly what you're asking for. The strategy that I employ works with weeks, as opposed to dates. In my solution, I have the latest week named as 'LCW' (last complete week) and the current week as 'WTD' as a separate field. I can then set a default selection in a week slicer to isolate these values, but it does not allow the use of a date slicer on a continuous date.